Ubuntu MATE 22.04 hangs with NVIDIA RTX 3050
I installed Ubuntu MATE 22.04 yesterday and installed NVIDIA drivers 535, and have noticed that it tends to hang the system. It can range from either opening a browser or after a long while of watching a video, or just having a few application windows open at once. This issue is more frequent with Nouveau drivers.
I've tried:

Switching drivers (Originally was on 545)
Adding nvidia-drm.modeset=1 to /etc/default/grub
Blacklisting Nouveau drivers using options nouveau modeset=0 in a conf in /etc/modprobe.d/
TTY keys don't work when it does crash

All of which worked fine for a while, but would crash regardless.
One of the messages from the dmesg logs that were last was:
[  217.530946] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
I was originally suspecting it to be the culprit however I am unsure if it is the cause or not.
The full output of sudo dmesg -w | grep -i nvidia is here.
Is there anything else I can do to fix this or find what is happening to cause these crashes? I'll provide more info about my system if needed.

Updating to 24.04 and changing the kernel seemed to fix it. I chose Liquorix personally but any others should work.
